Asp.Net MVC Application Failed to Start
I have an ASP.NET MVC application and it fails to start. The incident started to happen after the update of the Visual Studio. .NET version of the application is 4.6.2.
Here is the content of the web.config file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
        <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=public_key_token"/>
    </configSections>
    <appSettings configSource="Development.config"/>
    <system.web>
        <!-- <customErrors mode="Off" /> -->
        <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>

        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
        <!--<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />-->
        <!--<machineKey validationKey="machine_key" decryptionKey="description_key" validation="validation1" decryption="decryption1" ></machineKey>-->
        <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="tr-TR" uiCulture="tr-TR" fileEncoding="utf-8"/>

        <httpModules>
            <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
        </httpModules>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="Account/Login"/>
        </authentication>
    </system.web>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <publisherPolicy apply="no"/>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="public_key_token" culture="neutral"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
            <remove fileExtension=".woff2"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2"/>
        </staticContent>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1524288000"/>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules>
            <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
            <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
            </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
            <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=public_key_token"/>
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
            <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.18.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=public_key_token"/>
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
    <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
        <version number="*">
            <dataSources>
                <dataSource alias="STUDYINTURKEY" descriptor="descriptor)))) "/>
            </dataSources>
        </version>
    </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Context" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="connectionString"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
</configuration>

Here is the Global.asax.cs:
using WebApplication.Bll.UserLogBll;
using WebApplication.Dal.Concrete.EnetityFramework.Repository;

namespace WebApplication.Mvc
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        IVisitorLogService _visitorLogService = new VisitorLogManager();
        
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); 
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
        }

        protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Session.SessionID == "LogStart")
            {
                // User ziyaret bitiş
            }
        }

        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Session.SessionID == "LogStart")
            {
                // User ziyaret başlangıç
            }
        }

        protected void Application_EndRequest()
        {
        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
        }
    }
}

When I clicked the "Run" button at the upper section of Visual Studio, I get this error page:

What went wrong? Thanks in advance.

.NET 4.6.x is obsolete - you need to update it to .NET 4.8. You won't find any machines/servers running .NET 4.6.x today: if it runs 4.6.1 then it can be updated to 4.8 - and Windows Update will have done that for you... years ago.

I will update this as soon as possible, but now this issue is out of question for now.

The reason for the error is given in the HTTP 404 error page under the heading "Detailed error information" - have you read it? If not, why not? If you have read it, then what part of it don't you understand?

@tahasozgen please check my answer, I edited multiple times, and it is ready now. Hope that helps.

You don't see the exact error, since there is a misconfiguration as mentioned in the answer below. First thing you need to see exact error. Then you may understand what is the problem.
